# What reasons justify preventing a user from asking questions?

Tags: discussion

Why would I be prevented from asking questions if my questions are about the bible?

Comment: Biblical Hermeneutics is a somewhat specialized site. You can read about what's considered on topic on our [help center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In order to answer this question, however, we'd need to know a little bit more about what you are trying to ask about. Is there a particular question you'd like to ask, but can't?

Comment: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/256282)

Comment: Anyone can look at my  questions .  Did I ask an "inappropriate " question? Then  vote to close it.  But  to stop me from asking questions  without  specifying the reason why,  leaves  me wondering about the motives of those behind it.

Comment: I also dont know what was the reason. +1 for bringing that up.

Comment: @Tiago MartinsPeres. Thanks. I wonder  if  my  question  will  be  answered.

Answer (score 2):

9 out of your 26 questions have at least one downvote. Most likely that's the cause for your ban.

What can you do now? Don't delete the questions because that'd still count for the ban. Instead, edit them to improve their quality in hope other members will see it and reward the effort. That should suffice for the ban to be lifted up.

If you notice that after a few days nothing really changes, you can contribute to the community in some other ways to show how valuable your contributions are and eventually that ban will be lifted up.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPerez. Do you think stopping a user from asking questions because he has negative votes on his/her answers and questions without specifying the reasons why  automatically make the answers and or questions of that user wrong? Does that in itself justify stopping that user from asking questions?

Comment: That's an automatic filter used for prevention against low quality QAs. More about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60294/364217). If you have anything against that, the place to bring that up is in Meta StackExchange as that has to do with all communities. Would still edit the questions if I were you.

Comment: The negative voting and the stopping of a user from asking is automatic filtering?

Comment: No, only the stopping of a user from asking. I'm a fan of leaving comments when giving downvotes so that the OP can improve  based on it (if possible). Hope in your case users followed that principle too but I know not everyone proceeds that way for multiple reasons. The most common at my sight is to pass through review queues faster but not saying that the case there.